# Why UnicodeEncodeError raised only in emacs's python shell?

Tags: python, emacs, unicode, ascii

In emacs (use `run-python` command to call `python3`):

```
>>> sys.version
sys.version
'3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> data
data
'sp\xe4m'
>>> print(data)
print(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In terminal:

```
~$python3
Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data='sp\xe4m'
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> data
'späm'
>>> print(data)
späm
```

Does anyone have ideas about the reason that unicode string of Python works in terminal but not in emacs

(Version information of emacs : `GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2012-08-27 on bob.porkrind.org`)

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but it might help to include your version of emacs.

Comment: FWIW, I was not able to reproduce the problem on Ubuntu, emacs 23.3.1, python 3.2.2. (In a `M-x shell`, not through `run-python`, since for me that runs python2.)

Comment: @unutbu Thanks, can you try `C-u M-x` then `run-python`, and then emacs will enable you call python3

Comment: @unutbu Even I use `M-x shell ` to run python, the non-ascii characters still can't be displayed well

Comment: I tried `C-u M-x run-python python3` but was (still) not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @unutbu So this issue is only related with some versions of emacs...  thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is not related to the stdout or shell you are executing in. The default encoding is just the internal encoding that is used to encode Unicode strings.

The shell you are printing to however does not necessarily have the same encoding. You can get the encoding of stdout from `sys.stdout.encoding`. Unfortunately, Python has no means to change that, so you’d have to find out yourself how to change the shell encoding (In the Windows console, it’s done using `chcp` for example).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this is related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9876/861

Adding

```
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_ALL" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_CTYPE" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

to your `.emacs` solved the problem for me.

Comment: For me it was only necessary to execute the first of the three to fix my `UnicodeEncodeError` using python 3.6

Answer (score 2):

This work in my machine (Windows 7, Emacs 25.1)

In init.el set this:

```
(setenv "PYTHONIOENCODING" "utf-8")
```

(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

Type the following statement and then python works

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'
```